# Example 4.3.19 in Liu: unramification with schemes and numbers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

In exemple 4.3.19 of Liu's book one hase $L/K$ an extension of number fields with integer rings $\mathcal{O}_L$ and $\mathcal{O}_K$, $\mathfrak{q}\subseteq\mathcal{O}_L$ a prime ideal and $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{q}\cap\mathcal{O}_K$. Then the author explain why the scheme morphism $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_L\to\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_K$ is unramified in $\mathfrak{q}$ iff $\mathfrak{p}$ is not ramified in $\mathfrak{q}$ (if I well understand).

I see that unramifiaction of the morphism is equivalent with $\mathfrak{q}(\mathcal{O}_L)_\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{p}(\mathcal{O}_L)_\mathfrak{q}$ but I don't see why this is equivalent with $\mathfrak{p}$ is not ramified in $\mathfrak{q}$.

If $\mathfrak{p}$ is not ramified in $\mathfrak{q}$ then one has $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L=\mathfrak{q}\mathfrak{q}_2^{n_2}\ldots\mathfrak{q}_k^{n_k}$ so $\mathfrak{p}(\mathcal{O}_L)_\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{q}\mathfrak{q}_2^{n_2}\ldots\mathfrak{q}_k^{n_k}(\mathcal{O}_L)_\mathfrak{q}\subsetneq\mathfrak{q}(\mathcal{O}_L)_\mathfrak{q}$ because $\mathfrak{q}\mathfrak{q}_2^{n_2}\ldots\mathfrak{q}_k^{n_k}\mathcal{O}_L\subsetneq\mathfrak{q}$

Maybe my definition of $\mathfrak{p}$ is not ramified in $\mathfrak{q}$ is not correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the correct definition.

Let $A=\mathcal{O}_K$ and $B=\mathcal{O}_L$. Suppose that $\mathfrak{p}\in\text{spec}(A)$ and that $\mathfrak{p}B=\mathfrak{q}_1^{e_1}\cdots\mathfrak{q}_m^{e_m}$. Consider now the induced map $A_\mathfrak{p}\to B_{\mathfrak{q}_i}$ for any $i$. Then, by definition of $\text{spec}(B)\to\text{spec}(A)$ being unramified we know that  $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}B_{\mathfrak{q}_i}=\mathfrak{q}_iB_{\mathfrak{q}_i}$. But,

$$\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}B_{\mathfrak{q}_i}=\mathfrak{p}B_{\mathfrak{q}_i}=(\mathfrak{p}B)_{\mathfrak{q}_i}=(\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_m^{e_m})_{\mathfrak{q}_i}=(\mathfrak{q_i}B_{\mathfrak{q}_i})^{e_i}$$

Thus, we may conclude that $e_i=1$ for all $i$. The converse follows again from the centered equation.

Comment: There's something I don't understand: if one has $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}B_{\mathfrak{q}_i}=\mathfrak{q}_i^{e_i}B_{\mathfrak{q}_i}$ then $\mathfrak{p}B B_{\mathfrak{q}_i}=\mathfrak{q}_i^{e_i}B_{\mathfrak{q}_i}$ and as the two ideals $\mathfrak{p}B$ and $\mathfrak{q}_i^{e_i}$ are in $\mathfrak{q}_i$ then by description of localised ideals one should have $\mathfrak{p}B=\mathfrak{q}_i^{e_i}$ which is not right??

Comment: Maybe a problem with the formula $(\mathfrak{q}_1^{e_1}\cdots\mathfrak{q}_m^{e_m})_{\mathfrak{q}_i}=(\mathfrak{q}_i B_{\mathfrak{q}_i})^{e_i}$... or I missed something?

Comment: @GabrielSoranzo $\mathfrak{p}B$ isn't prime though.

Comment: @GabrielSoranzo In fact, this is kind of why there is only a bijection between primes, not general ideals. Localizing cuts off of $\mathfrak{p}B$ precisely the other primes--what is inverted.

Comment: For $(\mathfrak{q}_1^{e_1}\cdots\mathfrak{q}_m^{e_m})_{\mathfrak{q}_i}=(\mathfrak{q}‌​_i B_{\mathfrak{q}_i})^{e_i}$ the general formula is $S^{-1}IJ=(S^{-1}I)(S^{-1}J)$ I guess?

Comment: @GabrielSoranzo Sorry for the late reply--that's correct.